# Help with optimization

Tags: calculus

The rectangle located in the first quadrant and is basically inscribed under a decreasing curve.The lower left hand corner is at the origin and the upper right hand corner on the curve.
The equation is $y = 5 - 2x^2$. Please find the width, height and area of the largest such rectangle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:  If $(x,y)$ is the upper corner of the rectangle, you have $A=xy$.  Substitute in your equation for $y$ to get $A$ as a function of $x$.  Then take $\frac {dA}{dx}$ and set it to zero to get an equation in $x$.

Comment: Im not sure what to do from there. would the answer be -4

Comment: @MichaelRametta:  what do you get for $\frac {dA}{dx}$?  I get $x$ close to $+1$ and an area about 3

Comment: I am still confused can you please help me

Comment: @MichaelRametta: only if you show what you have tried.  I don't know where you are confused.  I gave a process, what steps can you do and what can you not?

Comment: and so A' (x) = 0 when x=1/2

Comment: @MichaelRametta: No.  What do you have for $A(x)$?